# When dealing with complex nested routes, should I validate parent ids?

Tags: api, rest, api-design

I think my original question got too far off topic from my very specific question. So I'm wiping it out and updating it with this.

Our backend api at the moment has some very nested resources. For example:

```
/master-schedules/{id}/courses/{id}/sections/{id}/rooms
```

In order to GET a room as an example, all I need is the {id} of the room and could (if the endpoint existed) just GET /rooms/{id}. Instead, I'm doing a GET to /master-schedules/{id}/courses/{id}/sections/{id}/rooms.

Looking at the code, the backend is doing 3 db calls to validate that the master-schedule exists, then the course exists, then the section exists. Really, all we need to know is that the section exists because if it exists then the others should exist.

**Should we be doing all these db calls in order to validate the parent resources?** It's not really the performance of the db etc that bothers me, it's more about the amount of boilerplate code being written for each endpoint. Maybe we just shouldn't have such nested resources?